# how does work offchain in substrate ( pokadot )

Tags: polkadot-js, polkadot, substrate-node-template, offchain-worker, substrate-parachain-template

I Wanna know about off-chain in the substrate ( Polkadot ) how does work?

How is it mine from the onchain ( main chain in Polkadot )?

maybe somebody wants to hack the off-chain and they do it a success, in this situation what does the onchain for reject the block or off-chain data?

and please explain how does work off-chain and how can send off-chain data to onchain ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is detailed docs on substrate.io
https://docs.substrate.io/reference/how-to-guides/offchain-workers/